# Spring display PDF to web

Tags: java, spring, pdf

I'm new to Spring, How can I display a PDF file from a specific path? The PDF file is available locally and I want to display it in `object` tag of the HTML. I have seen some tutorials which is I really don't understand.

The code is something like this. I'm not quite sure if this is really the thing I'm looking for.

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/files/{file_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public void getFile( @PathVariable( "file_name" )
    String fileName, HttpServletResponse response )
    {
        try
        {
            // get your file as InputStream
            InputStream is = ...
            // copy it to response's OutputStream
            IOUtils.copy( is, response.getOutputStream() );
            response.flushBuffer();
        }
        catch( IOException ex )
        {
            log.info( "Error writing file to output stream. Filename was '" + fileName + "'" );
            throw new RuntimeException( "IOError writing file to output stream" );
        }

    }
```

The value from the request mapping seems looks like an `EL` to me. I'm not quite sure. And in the `InputStream` what should I put there. Sorry for a noob question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `InputStream` you should put the object you create to access the file.

```
  InputStream is = = new FileInputStream("/pathToFile/"+ fileName);
```

Comment: Can you tell me about the `@RequestMapping( value = "/files/{file_name}",method = RequestMethod.GET )`, the {file_name} look like an `EL` to me.

Comment: It might be wildcard mapping.